# Creating a variable with the innerHTML of another website in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a javascript `alert()` with the innerHTML of `<p class="synopsis">...</p>` from a Netflix movie page in a Chrome Extension.

This is my background.js

```
window.onload = function() {

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    var synopsis = document.getElementsByClassName("synopsis").innerhtml;
    alert(synopsis);
});

}
```

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Get Synopsis",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Get synopsis",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "permissions":[ "tabs", "*://www.netflix.com/*" ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I believe `getElementsByClassName` returns an array or at least some sort of list of elements and thus `innerHTML` won't be available. Also, I'm pretty sure it's `innerHTML` (not `innerhtml`). Both of these errors should show up in the console though.

Edit: Because it's an array, you'll need to first select the element of the array you're after and *then* use `innerHTML`. So if you for example want the *first* element with the specified class you'd do `...getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. I made the changes you and fsacer suggested, but now the consol is telling me that the innerHTML is `undefined`. I've checked the source code of the page and there is definitely only one `class='synposis'` on the page. Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns array so you must access element using indexer like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    var synopsis = document.getElementsByClassName("synopsis")[0].innerHTML;
    alert(synopsis);
});

});
```

**EDIT:** Correction on event.

Comment: I tried your answer, and it returned this error: `Error in event handler for browserAction.onClicked: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at chrome-extension://.../background.js:5:66handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8`

Comment: The problem is you can't do that on window.onload because DOM isn't ready.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't `window.onload` instruct the script to wait until the DOM is ready?

Comment: No, try the edit.  You need to use something like `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: Even with the edit, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You can see that part of code working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dovmKQ. But I'm not sure about the Chrome's events.

Comment: i answered this yesterday

Answer (score 0):

existing answers point to actual errors in your code, but the real main issue is that you should look at the documentation about the architecture of a chrome extension.

particularly, document does not mean the document of the active tab on a background page.

instead you could use a content script and send a message from the popup code (not background) to the active tab asking for the synopsis.

there might also be a way to get the active tab html directly from background but i searched all permissions and didnt see any besides using a content script.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions